# Python/Selenium: "This site can't be reached" caused "unknown error: cannot determine loading status"

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm running a script that works well to scrape some data I need. The script crawl some existing URLs on a given web page and visit each URL to get the final URL. The problem occurs when the final URL is not found "**This site can't be reached**". The code crashes and I get this in the log:

```
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
    from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
    from tab crashed
    (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.135)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Here is the code I use to scrape the final URLs:

```
    #Open link (opens in new tab)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="popup__teaser"]/div[6]/div/div/a')
    elem.click()
    time.sleep(2)

    #wait for redirection to load - switch to the new tab - grab and print the new URL
    driver.get(driver.current_url)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
    URL= driver.current_url

    #Close active tab 
    driver.close()

    #switch to main tab
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

Can anybody help with this issue? It only happens when the redirection URL is not found. Thanks

EDIT: I've tried adding `chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')` but it didn't work.

EDIT2: [Here is the URL causing the crash](https://affbank.com/redirect/index?hash=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%3D%3D)

Comment: Add website URL as well

Comment: Done, just added the URL. Thanks

Comment: I think there is some problem with this URL it is redirecting somewhere

Comment: You are right, in fact the URL returns no browser response. I found a solution to my problem by following the anchor url rather than the href.

Answer (score 1):

Try importing requests and check the status code of the site. For a site to be active, it should normally have a status code of 200. If it does not have a status code of 200 then chances are it cannot be reached

```
import requests

if requests.get(url).status_code!=200:
```

Comment: You could check for the other status codes that may still have a working site.Like 301 and others